# Unable to create a Path object from a String

Tags: java, eclipse, io, path, nio

I'm following along the Basic I/O Tutorial on Oracle.com, but I'm having difficulty making a Path object:

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/tmp/foo");
```

Which gives the error:

```
error: The method get(URI) in the type Paths is not applicable for the arguments (String).
```

I'm on Linux and I'm working in Eclipse Kepler. I'm trying to access a text file in the current directory. Using Scanner and File I can work with the file, but I'd also like to fiddle around with a path to the file so I can continue with the tutorial.

edit: The entirety of the program is below. The second half is me being a rookie and confirming the file exists/works. When I comment out the Path definitions, I get the output of "Test" which is in the 'save.txt' file.:

```
package projectSARA;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String saveFile = "save.txt";
    Path p1 = Paths.get(saveFile);
    Path p2 = Paths.get("save.txt");

    File file = new File(saveFile);
    try{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    String test = in.next();
    System.out.println(test);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
}// end main

}
```

Additional: I've asked this question before, and was asked for edits. I added in the edits, waited a few days, but no more responses. Am I supposed to refresh it somehow, or contact the authors of the comments? I'm very new to Stack Exchange, but appreciate everyone's efforts immensely.

Comment: Is this a compile time error or run time error?  This works find for me using Netbeans, Java 7 and Mac OS

Comment: Also works for me in Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 with Java 7 and Mac OS

Comment: Paths.get(...) calls Path.of(...) so I'd call the latter.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631724/paths-get-vs-path-of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Paths.get("/some/path")` is a valid method call. If the code is as you posted it, this may be  a bug with Eclipse intentions.  Your error `The method get(URI) in the type Paths...` is not a javac error, it's an Eclipse error.

Your class is fairly simple, so try compiling it with javac or using some other IDE besides Eclipse and see if you get a compilation error.

Comment: It is a compilation problem, since it gets reported when running a .jar outside of Eclipse: java -jar mine.jar Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        The method get(URI) in the type Paths is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Answer (score 0):

In your line:

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/tmp/foo");
```

You are using a string while the get method is expecting an URI.

Just define your path as an URI first.

```
URI uri = null;
try {
    uri = new URI("file:///myFile.txt");  
             }
Path file=Paths.get(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Path p1 = Paths.get("/tmp/foo");

where Paths.get accepts only URI arguments so we need to provide like

```
Path dir = Paths.get(new URI("/tmp/foo"));
```

I guess, it will solve your issue.

Comment: There are actually two methods and the other one accepts a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but here's a simple workaround:

```
Paths.get("save.txt", "");
```

This will force the system to use the string-based get method instead of the URI.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the JRE to java 7 will solve this. On Eclipse go to project properties -> build path -> libraries -> select the JRE system library -> click edit -> change execution environment to jdk 7. Now you can pass String into Paths.get().