# Paths.get vs Path.of

Tags: java, java-11

As far as I can tell, `Paths.get` and `Path.of` seem to do exactly the same thing, turning one or more strings into a `Path` object; the documentations for [`Paths.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String) and [`Path.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) use the same wording. Are they in fact identical?

`Path.of` was introduced later.

*Conjecture:* it was introduced for the sake of a consistent `Foo.of` style. In that case, it would be considered preferable on consistency/aesthetic grounds?

Comment: I think you are correct. A quick search over the java discussion lists brought up this: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-dev/2018-March/004810.html Still reading though to write an answer.

Comment: I prefer `Path.of` because it doesn't require additional import

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Indeed, `Path.of` was later introduced.

> Conjecture: it was introduced for the sake of a consistent `Foo.of` style.

From the mailing list archive, this [method was once called `Path.get`](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-dev/2018-March/004810.html):

> The main changes in are in Path and Paths in java.nio.file.
>
> This patch copies the Paths.get() methods to static methods in Path.get() and modifies the former to call the latter respective methods. The Path specification is slightly cleaned up not to refer to Paths nor itself, e.g., “(see Path).” @implSpec annotations are added to Paths to indicate that the methods simply call their counterparts in Path.
>   ...

This was later changed when [Brian Goetz suggested it to be consistent with `Foo.of`](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-dev/2018-March/004828.html):

> Separately, Brian Goetz suggested off-list that it would be more 
>   consistent if these factory methods were named "of" so I assume the 
>   webrev will be updated to see how that looks.

Now to your last question: "In that case, it would be considered preferable on consistency/aesthetic grounds?"
In the [initial mail](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-dev/2018-March/004810.html) Brian Burkhalter said that he updated all references to the new method in `Path`:

> All source files in java.base are modified to change Paths.get() to Path.get() and to remove the import for Paths. ...

So I would therefore conclude that `Path.of` is indeed preferable to `Paths.get`.
Indeed, if you look at the [Javadoc for `Paths` for Java 13](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html) you will find this note:

> **API Note**:
>   It is recommended to obtain a `Path` via the `Path.of` methods instead of via the `get` methods defined in this class as this class may be deprecated in a future release.

Comment: Mind that NIO.2 was introduced in Java 7 when static methods in interfaces were not possible. So it needed a companion class, `Paths`. Using the factory method of the interface reduces the number of types, the code has to deal with. The naming style is just another point that has been revised as there was this opportunity.