# Why was Objects.toString added over String.valueOf?

Tags: java, api-design

In JDK 7, it appears that `Objects.toString` was added along with an overload.   This method calls String.valueOf, and the Javadocs specify that they have identical behavior. My question why was this method added when `String.valueOf` does the same thing already?

Comment: The question is specific to `Objects`, not `Object`

Comment: sorry, I missed the `s`... but then you better ask the developers. I can only guess: maybe it is considered better to be used in lambdas... or for some kind of symmetry, like that class also having `equals` and `hashCode`...

Comment: I would vote to close this as opinion-based, as with many "why did the designers..." questions, but I think there is hope for specific citation-based answers: I have unearthed the original thread discussing these additions [here](https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2009-September/002572.html), but I don't have the time to exhaustively read it right now.

Comment: similar question regarding `Path.of()` and `Paths.get()` - actually the only methods of `Paths`, so the whole class just for calling the `Path.of()` methods

Comment: @LouisWasserman I looked through some of that thread before posting here, but couldnt find an answer.   Presumably there is some technical need served by Objects.toString that String.valueOf does not.  That would mean there is an objective answer, not opinion based.

Comment: @CarlMastrangelo I wouldn't assume a technical need. Perhaps it's as simple as feeling that if `Objects` had existed at the start, it would have been the place for `toString`/`valueOf`, and so it would be confusing to leave it off, even when `valueOf` is identical.

Comment: Several methods in Objects are explicitly just for looking nice and readable as method references; I wouldn't at all assume that there's a technical need.  (Though being added in Java 7, not 8, makes that specific hypothesis less plausible.)

Comment: It might be that the designers of the `Objects` class decided that having `Objects.toString(o)` (as null-safe replacement for `o.toString()` together with the overload `toString(o, defaultString)`) nicely complement the `Objects.equals(o1, o2)` (as null-safe replacement for `o1.equals(o2)`) and `Objects.hashCode(o)` (as null-safe replacement for `o.hashCode()`)

Comment: Moot now since the question is closed.   The overload was not originally present ( https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/eca779ecad50 ), so and since the code was committed without commentary, I can only assume there was no reason.  

Objects.toString is undesirable because unlike the other two methods, it doesn't have a behavior difference.  When in code review, I had to do a double take to see why `Objects.toString` was used over `String.valueOf`.  It is a waste of time to remember what another function does, given that it provides no functional difference to the well known one.

Comment: As with [`Path.of` vs `Paths.get`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631724/paths-get-vs-path-of/58631951#58631951) this question might be answered without an own opinion by looking through [the old mailing list threads](https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2009-October/002878.html).

Comment: it is just *cosmetic*; as Thomas [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77902571/why-was-objects-tostring-added-over-string-valueof#comment137339427_77902571)